# Convert typeof(T) to T

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have this generic function:

```
public List<T> GetList<T>() {
    var businesType = typeof(T);
    var databaseType = AutoMapperConfiguration.TypeMapping[businesType];

    var databaseEntityList = DataModelAccess.GetEntityList(databaseType);

    var businessEntityList = Mapper.Map(databaseEntityList, databaseEntityList.GetType(), typeof(List<T>));
    return (List<T>)businessEntityList;

}
```

But what I want, instead to call DataModelAccess like that:

```
DataModelAccess.GetEntityList(databaseType);
```

is to send databaseType as Generic type, like that:

```
DataModelAccess.GetEntityList<DatabaseType>();
```

in order to have return of this method like `List<T>` .

Thank you!
P.S. The definition of DataModelAccess.GetEntityList(databaseType) is :

```
public static List<object> GetEntityList(Type databaseType)
{
    //get data from database
    //retunt it as List<object> <= and I dont like that
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code/definition of `DataModelAccess.GetEntityList()`

Comment: Why do you need this? Just don't like signature with Type as a parameter? It's not one line to achieve and might not be worthwile at all

Comment: I want this in order to be easily to be used by other programmers ( this will be a library). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function very like your `GetList<T>` should solve this issue for you.

```
public List<T> GetEntityList<T>() { }
```

You can then invoke it

```
typeof(DataModelAccess)
    .GetMethod("GetEntityList")
    .MakeGenericMethod(databaseType)
    .Invoke();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: well I don't think reflection is needed in this case, he already has a `T` to work with

Comment: Yes he does, but he determines T (databaseType) at runtime, so reflection is needed.

Comment: Oh!! You're right, I overlooked that! My bad! `T` isn't the type needed

Comment: Personally I think passing in the type, as the function currently stands, is a better option though.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the only option. I hoped, it will exist an other way, this one seems too expensive from my point of view.

Answer (score 2):

If your `GetEntityList` method returns a generic `List<object>` but all its items are of a single type, you can use [`IEnumerable.Cast<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341406.aspx) to turn it into a `List<T>`:

```
List<object> result = DataModelAccess.GetEntityList(databaseType);
List<T> databaseEntityList = result.Cast<T>().ToList();
```

Other than that, no you cannot call a non-generic method in a generic way without changing that method.

Comment: hm, I will try to use this. Thank you!